# Get new (v3 API) Facebook Place ID from old (v2 API) Place ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook are changing the IDs that are returned from their Places API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/

> Places Graph endpoints now return a new type of Place ID. Older versions of the API will continue returning the old type of IDs until August 1, 2018.

Does anyone know how to get the new `Place ID` from the old `Place ID` using Places API?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible this way around. Places used to be pages, and the new Place object has a `page` field that refers back to the page for the place. So getting from a new place to the old page id seems possible, not sure if there is a way to query it the other way around though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if all Place object ids are different to Page object ids?

Comment: They most likely will be. I don’t think there will be any old page id to new place id “translation” that you could do automatically on your end or anything like that.